# Why is a USB-C meter not bi-directional?

Tags: usb, power, usb-c

A USB-C measures current only if plugged in one direction or otherwise reads 0A current. If I connect two meters in opposite direction, one meter measures current but the other measures 0A current.

Since a USB-C device may switch roles from source to sink, or vice versa,   is there a better way to monitor current that may flow in either direction without hooking up two duplicate meters in the opposite direction?

[image: z1]

[EDIT]
[UT658Dual Manual](https://www.uni-trend.com/uploadfile/cloud/English%20manual/Electrical%20Power%20Testers/UT658ACDualLoad%20English%20Manual.pdf)
[UT658Dual Specification](https://www.uni-trend.com/uploadfile/2019/1118/20191118090419415.pdf)

Comment: Unfortunately, requests for hardware recommendations are considered off-topic on SuperUser.

Comment: @Spiff totally disagree. I can easily reworded the question to ask why the meter measures 0 current but the content of the question will be a lot less descriptive and carries no information.  The question DID NOT ask for recommendation - it's an accusation or misinterpretation. If my question mislead you to interpret such way then I'll gladly reword my question.

Comment: guys... I think I've been around SE long enough to know what's off topic and what's not. (1) This is NOT a duplicate (2) the question ask for NO recommendation (3) certainly NOT opinion based.  If you insist to vote it close, leave a comment with an objective arguments.

Comment: I just upvoted this question.  As currently written, it looks like a great question to me.

Comment: Can you provide manuals, screenshots of the port labels, so a proper answer can be formulated? This could come down to the cable you used or due to the how device was programmed to work.

Comment: Only the designer/manufacturer of this device can answer your question why it was built this way.

Comment: I actually have a meter that is bidirectional so there is no real reason beyond "it needs some extra design" and "your manufacturer decided it wasn't worth it". This isn't really a computer hardware or software problem, it's an electronic design one.

Comment: The irony here if this question is deemed off topic, all 6/7 related questions on the sides can arguably be straight out asking for hardware recommendation.  This question as I stand firmly is NOT a shopping recommendation by any objective standard, and certain NOT off-topic by any sense of proportion.  I vote to re-open this question with enough reasons given.

Comment: Voting to reopen as well.  No need to close this good question or single it out.  People really need to lighten up on closing things inappropriately.  As they say, give a person just a little power, and you can learn so much about them.  Give them a lot of power, and you'll learn everything you need to know.

Comment: I agree that the close reason is inaccurate, but still, this question can't be answered by anyone but the device manufacturer.